# How to keep open STDOUT and STDERR with Daemon::Simple

Tags: perl, exec, fork

I've been using [`Daemon::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~khs/Daemon-Simple-0.1/lib/Daemon/Simple.pm) to quickly Daemonise some scripts and also make them start/stop capable. However, some of these scripts are written in python, so I generally call `Daemon::Simple::Init()` then `exec()` the python script.

However, I've found that `Daemon::Simple::Init()` closes `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, and it seems as a result of this the python scripts break (just exit) when they write to `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. Reopening `STDOUT` and `STDERR` and redirecting them to a file before the exec does not help.

What I've found does help is changing the source of `Daemon::Simple` from this:

```
close(STDOUT);
close(STDERR);
```

to:

```
open STDOUT, "/dev/null"
open STDERR, "/dev/null"
```

If I then again open `STDOUT` and `STDERR` and redirect them to real files after calling `Daemon::Simple:Init()` like before, this time it works. It seems that closing `STDOUT` and `STDERR` and reopening somehow breaks them post `exec()`, but opening them to `/dev/null` and reopening them works fine.

Is there anyway I can reopen or keep open `STDOUT` and `STDERR` without modifying `Daemon::Simple` which survives an `exec()`?

Comment: [By definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29), a daemon process has no controlling terminal and no common file descriptors with the process that started it. So you cannot keep the original `STDOUT` and `STDERR` open. You can reopen them after the fork to something else, though.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "breaks them post `exec()`". Give an example of an operation you want to perform after calling `Daemon::Simple::Init()`

Comment: Nevermind - I think I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Are those the same lines you were using to try to reopen STDERR and STDOUT? If so the problem is likely that you're opening them for reading not for writing. Try using

```
open STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null';
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
use Daemon::Simple;

open(SAVEOUT, ">&STDOUT");
open(SAVEIN, "<&STDIN");

Daemon::Simple::init("daemon");

open(STDOUT, ">&SAVEOUT");
open(STDIN, "<&SAVEIN");

exec("python-script") or die "exec failed: $!";
```